# Error while using mycli

Tags: python, mysql

I got a table t, but while using `show create table t` in mycli, error occurs. Some other command got the same error.

[image]

By the way, my Python version is 2.7.13 and mycli's version is 1.11.0.

Comment: `show create table t\G`

Comment: @lad2025 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this problem reported in the mycli issues:

https://github.com/dbcli/mycli/issues/479

https://github.com/dbcli/mycli/issues/493

The developer's reply is:

> This appears to be an issue only on Python 2 when a row has newlines in it.
>
> The upcoming release of mycli fixes this.
>
> If you installed mycli via pip, you can fix this now by doing this:
>
> ```
> $ pip install -U cli_helpers
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My os is mac, and `brew search cli_helpers` get s no item. So it seems what I can do is to expected that the next version of mycli can fix this BUG.